# iOS - Setting delegate of input stream to another class

Tags: ios, delegates, inputstream, nsinputstream, cfreadstream

i am wondering that if it is possible to set the delegate of input stream to another class. So far all examples i have encountered are with self:
`[inputStream setDelegate:self]`.
I want to set delegate to another class like a `ViewController` not self. Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you solve the problem? Or is it still open?

Comment: I searched delegation mechanism but later i noticed notification center mechanism is more suitable for me. I am creating my singleton `TCPConnection` object and when i get input from server and i post the notification to view controller class to take care of response and make modifications in interface. Thanks for your advices. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your `ViewController` is responding to `NSStreamDelegate`, you can initiate an instance of the controller and set the delegate as usual.

```
@interface ViewController : NSOperation<NSStreamDelegate>
...
```

-

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[inputStream setDelegate:vc];
```

for example

*update:*

use an **id** or `UIViewController<NSStreamDelegate>` variable in the `TCPConnection` class to hold the parent.

For example:

```
// TCPConnection.h

@interface TCPConnection : NSOperation<NSStreamDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, assign) UIViewController<NSStreamDelegate> parent;

-(id)initWithParent:(UIViewController<NSStreamDelegate> *)p_parent;
...
```

...

```
// TCPConnection.m

-(id)initWithParent:(UIViewController<NSStreamDelegate> *)p_parent
{
    self = [super init];
    self.parent = p_parent;
    return self;
}

// UIViewController<NSStreamDelegate>.m

TCPConnection *connection = [[TCPConnection alloc] initWithParent:self];
```

Or a singlton solution, where you always call only

```
TCPConnection *connection = [TCPConnection sharedInstance];
```

and have only one instance of this class. For the most cases the best way ;)

Comment: Thanks but i think this is a little bit hardcoded because in my mechanism i want to assign that `ViewController` dynamically. For example i create a class named `TCPConnection` which has attributes like inputStream and outputStream. With this i can create this object in every `ViewController` in my project. The problem is, in TCPConnection class how can i know which `ViewController` created the `TCPConnection` object so i can set as delegate that `ViewController`. Do i make myself clear? :)

Comment: you can pass the class that created the instance to your TCPConnection (id parent). Already thought if a singleton solution could be good here? So only your TCPConnection handles everything and is just adjusted by the other classes? ;)

Comment: Thank you for your advice i will consider that. :)

Comment: updated with an example for assigning parent. hope you know how singletons work. by specific questions feel free to ask ;) if it helped you, please accept and/or vote up :)

Answer (score 0):

You can typecast the delegate and set it to some particular delegate and that will get called.