# connect IBOutlet to textViewDidEndEditing

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a UITextView:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextView *notesTv;
```

This was created by ctrl-dragging from the Main.storyboard to my .m file.  This is field will be used by the user to add a note.  My goal is to save the contents to NSUSerDefaults without having a save button.  I have used NSUserDefaults before so that is not the issue.

I want to use `UITextViewDelegate's textViewDidEndEditing` delegate method to save user input once they are done typing in a note.

When I ctrl-click on the UITextView in storyboard, I don't see a way to connect this to the `textViewDidEndEditing` delegate.  How can I get this method called once the user stops editing the note?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set delegate programmatically for same class

`notesTv.delegate=self;` and for other class
[iOS - Setting delegate of input stream to another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590265/ios-setting-delegate-of-input-stream-to-another-class)

and then write this code in `textViewDidEndEditing`:

```
  NSString *valueToSave = self.notesTv.text;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"preferenceName"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```